# Viable way to set LiveData off of the main thread

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

Using `LiveData` to signal a fragment to update it's display based on work done off of the main thread can be done by the `postValue()` function instead of `setValue()` but it has the problem that every posted value may not be observed on the main thread in the fragment.

A simple way to solve the problem is set the value from the worker running on `Dispatchers.IO` using `withContext`. Below is simple extension function that decides if this is needed using `@OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)`, which suggests this is a bad idea:

```
    companion object {
        @OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)
        suspend fun WorkingDepth.resetDepthOnMain() {
            if (currentCoroutineContext()[CoroutineDispatcher].toString() == "Dispatchers.Main") {
                resetDepth()
            } else {
                coroutineScope {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        // This is the technique to ensure that the main thread sees
                        // the notification. If done off the main thread via a post
                        // it is not guaranteed that the observer will get the notification.
                        resetDepth()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The "opt in" annotation is avoided by treating all dispatchers as not `Dispatchers.Main`. Probably the unnecessary overhead is inconsequential, but the nagging question remains why is it not built in to "set on main" instead of "post and hope off of main".

Setting off of main throws an exception, so another way is the catch the exception and then switch threads and try again.

In a simple example where the live data is supposed to show landmarks along a work path it was seen that some expected landmarks do not get shown with "post and hope".

Comment: I don't really follow you. Could you elaborate more on what is the problem with `postValue()`? If using coroutines then yes, switching to `Dispatcher.Main` is the way to go. What is the problem with this approach? Also, your extension function does more or less the same as `Dispatchers.Main.immediate`.

Comment: `postValue()` does not  guarantee every posted value is observed, i.e. two values may be posted but only the last observed. I was trying to write a function in a library that would be more efficient if the method was called on Main with a conditional based on the current context. Looking at the `withContext()` code I see now this is built in.

Comment: I'm not an Android dev, but tbh, it looks to me like a misuse of `LiveData`. It is not for handling streams of events, etc., but for storing the current value. This behavior of `postValue()` is not a technical limitation, but its intended behavior. By using `setValue()` you are probably guaranteed to observe all values, because it calls observers synchronously, but missing a value of `LiveData` should not be a concern in the first place.

Comment: Ohh, actually it is not entirely guaranteed, even while using `setValue()`. For example, if one observer modifies the value, other observers won't see the previous one: https://gist.github.com/broo2s/9e8a40283cb8ea7334a6d1169ab37b83 This code may look pretty silly, but in practice we usually change something in response to some events, so while using multiple observers it is easy to trigger such scenario. Maybe there are other similar corner cases.

Comment: I use the "EventData" model where the data is wrapped in an object that records observation allowing a "react only to observed for the first time" behavior. This makes live data more like a button click and it seems to work well in practice. Is there a better system for reacting to events generated in a view model in a lifecycle appropriate way?

Answer (score 0):

The `withContext()` method already includes the optimization suggested in the question.

This is explained in the comment for the fast paths in the coroutine library:

```
// FAST PATH #1 -- new context is the same as the old one
...
// FAST PATH #2 -- the new dispatcher is the same as the old one (something else changed)
...
```

Bottom line: If you must ensure execution on `Main` just wrap in a `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` block.